# Select items per page into Angular and send param to Spring

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, angular10, angular11

I'm trying to implement Spring pagination with Angular. I tried this code:

***Search DTO:***

```
public class ClassCategoriesSearchParams {
    private String title;
    private String type;
    private LocalDateTime publishedAt;
}
```

***Endpoint:***

```
    @PostMapping("/find")
    public Page<ClassCategoriesFullDTO> search(@Valid ClassCategoriesSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {

        Page<ClassCategoriesFullDTO> list = classCategoriesRestService.findClasses(params, pageable);
        return list;
    }

    public Page<ClassCategoriesFullDTO> findClasses(ClassCategoriesSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
        Specification<Product> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (params.getTitle() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("title"), params.getTitle()));
            }
            if (params.getType() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("type"), params.getType()));
            }
            if (params.getPublishedAt() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get("publishedAt"), params.getPublishedAt()));
            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };
        return classCategoriesService.findAll(spec, pageable).map(classCategoriesMapper::toFullDTO);
    }
```

Angular code:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between p-2">
        <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="totalItems" [(page)]="page" [pageSize]="size" (pageChange)="pageChange($event)">
        </ngb-pagination>

        <select class="custom-select" style="width: auto" [(ngModel)]="size" (ngModelChange)="sizeChange($event)">
          <option [ngValue]="1">1 items per page</option>
          <option [ngValue]="2">2 items per page</option>
          <option [ngValue]="4">4 items per page</option>
          <option [ngValue]="6">6 items per page</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Typescript code:

```
export class ClassListComponent implements OnInit {

  public page = 0;
  public size = 1;
  public totalItems = 0;

  public productList = [];

  public classes = [
    {
      id: null,
      productImage: null,
      summary: '',
      title: '',
      imgSrc: null
    }
  ];

  public loading = false;

  constructor(
    private _classService: ClassService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getClassList();
    this.getAllProducts();
  }

  private getClassList(): void {
    this._classService.getCategories().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.classes = [];
        this.classes = Object.values(data);
        this.classes.forEach(element => {
          this.getCategoryImage(element);
        });
      },
    );
  }

  public getCategoryImage(element): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this._classService.getCategoryImage(element.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        element.imgSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(data));
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
  }

  private getAllProducts(): void {
    this._classService.getAllProducts(this.page, this.size).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.productList = [];
        this.productList = response.content;
        this.totalItems = response.totalElements;
      }
    );
  }

  public pageChange(event): void {
    this.page = event - 1;
    this.getAllProducts();
  }

  public sizeChange(event): void {
    this.size = event;
    this.getAllProducts();
  }
}
```

Service:

```
 public getAllProducts(
    page?: number,
    size?: number
  ): Observable<GenericListDTO<any>> {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    if (page !== null) {
      params = params.set('page', page.toString());
    }
    if (size) {
      params = params.set('size', size.toString());
    }
    return this.http.post<GenericListDTO<any>>(`${this.url}/find`, {}, { params });
  }


export class GenericListDTO<T> {

  content: T[] = [];
  pageable: any = {};
  totalPages: number;
  totalElements: number;
  size: number;
  numberOfElements: number;
}
```

I have this issue: When I set the number of items per page to be 1, in order to get the first item I need to send param page = 0. I can set the logic of page change function to behave like expected but my pagination component will not correctly focus the selected page. Maybe this could be fixed with some css overriding, but I think the cleaner solution would be to change this in BE function. Do you know how this can be fixed?

Comment: In `sizeChange` method don't you need to set `this.page = 0` as well? :)

Comment: it's not helping for solving the problem

Comment: @PeterPenzov, see the docs about httpClient.post, you are sending the params as options, you need use the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a new state variable for your service with one subtracted instead of modifying `page` variable.

Alternately, Spring has support for indexing pagination starting from 1. Two way you can configure

1. `spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true` in your application properties
2. Through java config, modify the resolver bean

```
PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested how I can solve the issue into my source code?

Comment: I think your problem is that you have `page = 0` initially and normally page numbers starts from 1 in ui, so when you have page value as 0 you don't have that highlighted and I don't think css overriding will solve anything. To solve this in UI, you don't even need to maintain new state, as I said above, because using 2 variables for same intent will cause confusion, instead simple thing to do is initialize `page=1` and modify page `this.page = event ` (no need to decrement) and in `getAllProducts()` do `this._classService.getAllProducts(this.page - 1, this.size)`

Comment: ok, this proposal is possible. In general what is the best way to solve this? Maybe to handle it in BE?

Comment: You can go with BE approach if you want this behaviour consistent across the application. You can use one of the ways I have provided above to configure. One weird thing Ive noticed in JPA pagination is, even if you start the page from 1(by enabling OneIndexedParameters), your api will still accept 0 as a valid page param and will give you the response, so basically for page 0 and 1 both you will get same first page as the response, and in the response, page value will be set to 0 even if your request parameter is 1, its not a problem if you are ignoring page information returned in response.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: It's not an answer, only a comment

if you're using httpClient, the post must be

```
this.http.post<GenericListDTO<any>>(`${this.url}/find`, {
   page:page,
   size:size,
});
```

Forget httpParams the syntax is `http.post(<url>,<obj>,<options>}`, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request), the third argument are options and it's used when you don't send a json or you need an especial headers